# Bidirectional bar chart with positive labels on both sides ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm try to create a bidirectional bar chart in ggplot where axis labels and data labels both above and below the axis are positive. So for example, if your data was:

```
myData <- data.frame(category = c("yes", "yes", "no", "no"), month = c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Feb'), values = c(6, 5, 4, 3))
```

I'd want two columns, one for January and one for February, where the 'yes' values appeared pin bars pointing up with positive axis and data labels, and the 'no' values pointing down, also with positive axis and data labels. There would be a '0' value bar in between them. Is this possible in ggplots, and if so, how can it be accomplished? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? We can pass the "no"s as negatives, but have ggplot display them as positive values. Same thing for the labels.

```
myData$values2 <- ifelse(myData$category == "no", -1 * myData$values, myData$values)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = myData) + geom_bar(aes(x=month,y=values2,fill=category),stat="identity",position="identity") +
                        geom_text(aes(x=month,y=values2,label=abs(values2)),vjust = ifelse(myData$values2 >= 0, 0, 1)) +
                        scale_y_continuous(labels=abs)
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks very much.

Comment: As a follow up to that, can I make the Y axis both absolute and formatted in dollars?